# Fetching data (N<->N relationship) in one SELECT and presenting it as headers+column data

Tags: php, sql

Say I have a table containing articles (article_id, article_name) and another table containing the names of people (person_id, person_name) that ordered the articles. Plus an intermediary table, say articles-people (article_id, person_id).

Is there an elegant way I could do a single SELECT to get all the articles and the associated purchasers such that the articles would each listed in headers and the people are listed under the respective articles they've bought?

Also, is there a SELECT that would fetch the needed information but avoid a result like this (which looks like a badly structured DB):

- article_id:1,article_name:penlight,purchaser_id:1, purchaser_name:fred
- article_id:1,article_name:penlight,purchaser_id:2, purchaser_name:albert
- article_id:1,article_name:penlight,purchaser_id:3, purchaser_name:sonia
- ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should print out rows with values.

```
   $res = mssql_query('SELECT *
        FROM articles a
        join articles-people ap on a.article_id=ap.articleid
        join people p on ap.person_id=p.personid');

    $results = array();
    $finalResuls = array();
    while($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
       $results[] = $row;
    }

    foreach($results as $result)
    {
       /* This makes an array with key:value pairs as string. */
       foreach($result as $k => $v)
       {
          $finalResults[] = $k . ': ' . $v;
       }
       $string = '';
       /* Will concatenate data for each result row into a single string */
       foreach($result as $k => $v)
       {
          $string .= $k . ': ' . $v;
       }
       $finalResults[] = $string;
    }
```

So that you can have both solutions in the same post, here is the solution you were talking about with JNK.

```
$res = mssql_query('SELECT * from article');

$results = array();
while($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
   $id = $row['article_id'];
   $res2 = mssql_query("SELECT * from people p join articles-people ap on p.person_id=ap.person_id where ap.article_id='$id'");
   while($row2 = mssql_fetch_assoc($res2))
   {
      foreach($row2 as $k => $v)
      {
         $results[$id][] = $k . ': ' . $v;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: My bad.  I read the question again, and have edited my answer to print out the data as the OP wanted.

Comment: Yes, it does work. The issue, which I might not have explained clearly, is when you decide to display it. Either you display it as a series of lines (article + person) causing a lot of redundancy or you have to take the step of saving the article name and skipping it's display until articleA != articleB.

Comment: Are you saying you want each row of $finalResults to contain a string that has ALL of the values from that resulting row?

Comment: I edited it to also do the string thing I mentioned in the comment above.  You can select which way you want to go.  If I still did not answer your question, please let me know and I will edit or add something to give it to you.

Comment: Just saw you updated the code snippet. This is a step in the right direction. From what JNK has said an optimal solution is probably to use two queries, one for fetching the articles+ids to form a first loop and another one to fetch the purchasers based on the ids already fetched.

Comment: After reading your question again, I hope my updated answer contains what you are looking for.  I added what you were talking about with JNK.  It should produce the array structure you are looking for.  Where $id is, you can either use the article_id or the article_name field.  I just chose article_id to keep it simple.

Comment: Thanks Kyle. Much appreciated. Will give you a mention on my blog.

Comment: No problem.  Hope this helped you out.  Send me the link to your blog.  Always interested in reading things like this.

Answer (score 2):

**Aesthetic or display requirements like that should be handled in your application layer, not at the database layer.**

Getting a DB to return unassociated rows is possible but not recommended.  What you are basically asking for is to return the data without the relational information, which can cause issues.

It's a much better idea to return the data that you need, then filter the display accordingly. SQL is not optimized for work like this, and it will be much slower and much more cumbersome to format the display at the database level than at the app level.

Comment: I like the distinction between the application and database layer. It didn't feel right so I had to ask. What could I do from a pratical point of view? Cycle through the articles in a loop and get the purchaser information for each in turn?

Comment: @James - yes that probably would be the most logical.  I think Kyle is close to a solution for that below.